# what is \ used for in PHP namespace or class elements

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I been working on PHP framework for many years that I maintain for our internel closed source project.

While I updating this and keeping to coding standards with PHP 7 I notice that alot of developers use \ in there classes and namespaces that are called within the code.

for example

```
class ClassName extends ParentClass implements
    \ArrayAccess,
    \Countable,
    \Serializable
{
    // constants, properties, methods
}
```

or for example calling the class within functions of the classes

```
public function featured()
{
    // Check for request forgeries
    \Session::checkToken() or jexit(\Text::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

    $user   = \Factory::getUser();
    $ids    = $this->input->get('cid', [], 'array');
    $values = ['featured' => 1, 'unfeatured' => 0];
    $task   = $this->getTask();
    $value  = \ArrayHelper::getValue($values, $task, 0, 'int');
}
```

why is \ used and what is it purpose since it can work without \ as well.

as I cant see any information online what the use of the \ is for in classes and namespaces.

Comment: using \ at the start specifies the class is in the global namespace.  It may work without it, but if you start declaring your own namespaces you need it as it's a different namespace to your current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

When executing a file, it has it's own namespace. Look at this code from the above page:

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;
class Exception extends \Exception {}

$a = new Exception('hi'); // $a is an object of class A\B\C\Exception
$b = new \Exception('hi'); // $b is an object of class Exception

$c = new ArrayObject; // fatal error, class A\B\C\ArrayObject not found
?>
```

`$a = new Exception('hi');` uses the Exception class in the current namespace i.e. A\B\C

`$b = new \Exception('hi');` uses the global class [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php)

Comment: awesome, this was what I was looking for as I was not even sure what the point of \ was used for in namespaces. Now this makes sense. so this also stop conflicts like same names but different frameworks as long we use namespace A\B\C as Example; and call \Example::method();